# How to use VS and EF to access databases like Oracle and others?

Tags: visual-studio, oracle, database-connection

What options do I have to connect from `VS 2010` to other databases `like Oracle etc.`? What's the best solution?

Now I'm using `entity framework` (for MSSql DB) and would like to know if it's posssible to use it also for `Oracle`? I think there are some third party solutions but want to avoid them because of the costs.

Thanks in advance.

Regards.

Answer (score 0):

There is this possibility

http://linqtooracle.codeplex.com/

then there is nhibernate

And also this other one

http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/topics/dotnet/index-085163.html

Answer (score 0):

You could just install the [Oracle Data Access Components](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/topics/dotnet/utilsoft-086879.html) (ODAC) that automatically integrate with Visual Studio.  Other databases would likely have something similar.